# How to set the current context to a variable? (loadSubscript)

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, loading

Everytime I need to load a script with [loadSubscript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/mozIJSSubScriptLoader) I have to copy all "variables needed" to that context. Eg:

```
var ctx;
ctx.window = window;
ctx.console = window.console;
ctx.MyOwnClass1 = MyOwnClass1;
ctx.MyOwnClass2 = MyOwnClass2;
ctx.MyOwnClass3 = MyOwnClass3;

Services.scriptloader.loadSubScript("file://" + filePath, ctx, "UTF-8");
```

If I have 2 or 3 classes it's not a problem, but now I need the context knows 20 classes. So, I think there must be some way to set the current context to a variable. Something like:

```
var ctx = this.context;
```

Do you know how? Some idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use your own context as the prototype for the JavaScript context you load scripts into. If `ctx` is a regular object then you can use [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create):

```
var ctx = Object.create(window);
```

If `ctx` is a sandbox then you can use the [`sandboxPrototype` option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Components.utils.Sandbox#Sandbox_options):

```
var ctx = new Components.utils.Sandbox(systemPrincipal, {sandboxPrototype: window});
```

All properties available on `window` (including global functions/variables) will be automatically available on the `ctx` object.

*Note*: I'm assuming here that `window` is your global object (the object where global variables are defined). This will be true for code running inside a XUL/HTML document. However, code running inside a sandbox (e.g. `bootstrap.js` of bootstrapped add-ons) won't have a `window` object - there you can only access the global object as `this` in the top-level code.

Comment: Using this was the best solution!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try setting context, `ctx` to either `this` or `null`.  The *loadSubscript* documentation does state that it's an optional parameter.

---

**other answer from earlier edit:**

If you're daring, you could try fiddling with:

`Object.keys(this)` or `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this)`;

With Firefox's *devtools:scratchpad*:

```
var v1,v2,v3;
function MyClass1(){};
function MyClass2(){};
function MyClass3(){};
[Object.keys(this).join(", "),Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this).join(", ")].join("\n");

/*
outputs:
__SCRATCHPAD__, v1, v2, v3, MyClass1, MyClass2, MyClass3
Object, Function, eval, Components, ... ... , ArrayBuffer, WeakMap, Map, Set, Proxy
*/
```

With that you can put together a snippet to filter the class names of interest like this (with `this` in the global scope):

```
Object.keys(this).forEach(function(key){
    if(key.match(/^SomeNamespacedClassName/)){
        ctx[key] = this[key];
    }
});
```

Yeah, it might be tacky, but whatever works.